# Redirect duplicate urls using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i need help with htaccess advanced redirect.
Like i have some pages in my blog,

```
URL example site.com/en/post-detail/90
```

User can access same page by link

```
 site.com/en/post-detail/90/(anything after slash)
```

so i want to redirect all requests like

```
 site.com/en/post-detail/90/(anything) to site.com/en/post-detail/90.

/en/ - is various, it can be Ru, pt, it, fr etc.
/90/ - is the id of post, so it is always numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((en|ru|pt|it|fr)/post-detail/([0-9]+))/.+$ /$1
```

Comment: Hey, your code worked very well, just another little think, can you help me with it ? 
if i add /? it redirect me to /en/post-detail/90?